# Как преобразовать формат даты - поле сущности, используя spring initbinder?

Tags: java, spring, mvc, controller

Описание поля сущности:

```
@Column
@NotNull(message = "Поле не может быть NULL")
@Past(message = "Время должно быть в прошлом")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date date_of_birth;
```

jsp - файл

```
  <springForm:input id="date" path="date_of_birth" type="text" name="date_of_birth" value="${student.date_of_birth}" required="required" />
  <br/>
  <springForm:errors path="date_of_birth" cssClass="error" />
```

файл - mask.js, для ввода значения по маске

```
$(function(){
    $("#date").mask("99.99.9999", {placeholder: "дд.мм.гггг" }); });
```

метод @InitBinder

```
@InitBinder//(value="date_of_birth")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(true);
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "date_of_birth", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));

}
```

Дата вводится в текстовое поле на форме по шаблону мм.дд.гггг, а выводится обратно на форму в формате гггг-мм-дд. Как привести к первому формату - мм.дд.гг?